# How to separate digits from the end of a php string and save them into different variables

Tags: php, split

I am looking to separate digits that are present at the end of a string e-g 'Hello1221World987'
what I need is in $var1 = 'Hello1221World' and $var2 = 987.
I have looked into it and be able to to get var1 from this

```
$var1 = preg_replace("/[\s+\d+]{1,}$/","",$alias );
```

In $var1 I am getting the required result.
but is there any way I can get the last number too in $var2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look for anything not greedy `(.*?)` and then digits `(\d+)` to the end `$`:

```
preg_match("/(.*?)(\d+)$/", "Hello1221World987", $vars);
```

Now you have `$vars[1]` and `$vars[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parenthesized subpatterns](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to capture the different parts of the string into variables:

```
$str = 'Hello1221World987';
if (preg_match('/(.+?)(\d+)$/', $str, $match)) {
    // $match[1] now contains "Hello1221World"
    // $match[2] now contains "987"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex for the solution. That's great.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the last number (capture the delimeter and throw away empties).

```
<?php
$str = 'Hello1221World987';
list($var1, $var2) = preg_split(
    '/([0-9]+)$/',
    $str,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);
var_dump($var1, $var2);
```

Output:

```
string(14) "Hello1221World"
string(3) "987"
```